# C# events message

Tags: c#, events

This question is kind of basic but i just started with coding,
im trying to create an event's message but it doesnt let me..

```
namespace Homework_Excercise
{
    public delegate void bdateHandler();

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            p.name = Console.ReadLine();
            string tmp = p.name;
            p.happybday += new bdateHandler(bday_msg(tmp));
            Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
            p.age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    
        }
        static void bday_msg(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Happy birthday to you!\nHappy birthday to you!\nHappy birtday dear {0}!", name);
        }
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
namespace Homework_Excercise
{
    class Person
    {
        public event bdateHandler happybday;

        private int Age;

        public int age
        {
            get { return Age; }
            set { Age = value; }
        }
        private string Name;

        public string name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you mean it won't let you?

Comment: you aren't raising the event anywhere.

Comment: You should look at how to raise events. You will find tutorials on how to raise them.

Comment: Also, your delegate signature doesn't match the function you are trying to call

Comment: It says "Method name expected", while i wrote it.. the error's shows up at  line "p.happybday += new bdateHandler(bday_msg(tmp));"

Comment: You should try practicing the example on MSDN to get more clearly about event before doing this excersice

Comment: your delegate doesn't take a string parameter, but the method you're trying to feed to it does

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is in the

```
  p.happybday += new bdateHandler(bday_msg(tmp));
```

it should be

```
  p.happybday += new bdateHandler(bday_msg);
```

since you should assign a *method*, not *method's result*. Next your problem is 
that your custom delegate should accept `String` value (since `bday_msg` does) and it doesn't.

A better approach is using standard *EventHandler* instead of custom delegate:

```
class Person {
  // there's a good standard class for it, do not re-invent the wheel
  public event EventHandler HappyBirthday;
  ...
}
...
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Person p = new Person();
  ...
  // assign the method, not its result
  p.HappyBirthday += bday_msg;
  ...
}

static void bday_msg(Object sender, EventArgs args) {
  Person person = sender as Person;

  // So you have Person and you can take any property you like, e.g. "name"
  Console.WriteLine("Happy birthday to you!\nHappy birthday to you!\nHappy birtday dear {0}!", person.name);
}
```

and, finally, you have to *raise the event*: somewhere in `Person` class should appear something like

```
  if (null != HappyBirthday)
    HappyBirthday(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: `bday_msg` should be `bday_msg(object sender, EventArgs args)` to match the signature of an `EventHandler`.

Comment: @Erik: thank you! I've edited the code (including `EventArgs.Empty` when raising event as well)

Comment: +1 for using Yoda tense at the end.  Lesson to the OP (and others): As a good defensive coding practice, always compare the constant first and the object second.  Otherwise you eventually write `if (HappyBirthday = null) {...}` and FAIL ensues.

Answer (score 1):

You need some modification in `Person` class and replace `p.happybday += new bdateHandler(x => bday_msg(tmp));` with `p.happybday += bday_msg;` from `Main` method

```
namespace Homework_Excercise
{
    class Person
    {
        public delegate void bdateHandler(string message);
        public event bdateHandler happybday;
        public void RaiseEvent(string message)
        {
            if (happybday != null)
            {
                happybday(message)
            }
        }
        private int _age;

        public int age
        {
            get 
            { 
                 return _age; 
            } 
            set 
            { 
                 _age = value;
                 if (/*condition with age*/)
                 {
                     RaiseEvent(Name);
                 } 
            }
        }
        private string Name;

        public string name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets run through the accepted way of creating events, first if you want an event to have arguments, create a class that holds them:

```
public class BirthdayEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public BirthdayEventArgs(string message) { Message = message; }
}
```

You see that this class deriveds from `EventArgs` which is a common base class for event arguments. The class doesn't do much, just assigns the `message` to the `Message` property, but it could be expanded on to include additional information.

Next, lets look at how we implement the `Person` class to handle this event:

```
public class Person
{
    public event EventHandler<BirthdayEventArgs> HappyBirthday;

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void ItsMyBirthday()
    {
        if (HappyBirthday != null)
            HappyBirthday(this,
                new BirthdayEventArgs(
                    string.Format("{0} birthday is today and is {1} years old!",
                    Name, Age)));
    }
}
```

The creation of the `EventHandler` uses a generic called `EventHandler<T>` where `T` is a class that derives from `EventArgs`. Since we have our `BirthdayEventArgs` class that derives from it, we don't have to explicitly create delegates for this, it uses a standard one.

You'll also notice how we raise the event in the `ItsMyBirthday` method. First we check if the event is null (if there are no subscribers) and only if there are subscribers, we raise the event by calling the event like a method. We pass in a new `BirthdayEventArgs` object with our message, in this case a "John Smith birthday is today and is 142 years old" string. (**Note:** its also common practice to copy the event handler to a temporary variable before raising the event, this is for thread safety but I'll leave that as a different topic).

Now lets look at how to handle this in the `Main` method:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create the person
        Person p = new Person() { Name = "Joe Smith", Age = 142 };

        p.HappyBirthday += HappyBirthday;  //Subscribe to the event

        p.ItsMyBirthday(); //Raises the event

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void HappyBirthday(object sender, BirthdayEventArgs e)
    {
        //sender is the Person, and it has event arguments
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

This is pretty simplified from what you have, but you can change it to take input from the user. The event handler is declared as `p.HappyBirthday += HappyBirthday;` where `HappyBirthday` on the right side matches the delegate signature for the event.

Inside the event handler, you get a `sender` which is a boxed version of `Person` that raised the event, along with the event arguments object.

If you would like to see this run, see the [.NET Fiddle Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AJoNjm)